# Generic method returning generic type

Tags: c#, generics, return

I am using a restclient that accepts a type, which is later converted to the correct `IRestResponse`.

```
IRestResponse<MyClassA> response = client.Execute<MyClassA>();
```

Since `MyClassA` can also be `MyClassB` or `MyClassC` I thought about making a generic method which could handle this. However without any luck. This is my attempt:

public interface IRestClient{
IRestResponse response = PerformExecuteClient()

```
private RestResponse<T> PerformExecuteClient<T>() {
    return client.Execute<T>();
}
```

The compiler tells me that `client.Execute<T>` does not accept abstract types. Which makes sense, but I have no idea how else to make this method. Is it possible what I am trying to achieve here?

Additional information based on some comments. As Brains Mains suggested, the method is not accepting the abstract type here.

```
public interface IRestClient{
    IRestResponse<T> Execute<T>(IRestRequest request) where T : new();
}
```

Comment: Can you show the class of client and in particular the signature of Execute<T>?

Comment: Why do you need this method instead of using `client.Execute<T>` directly? What is the compilation error you get? Does `client.Execute<T>` have a `new()` constraint on `T`?

Comment: Follwing Lee's comment you can do: `var response = client.Execute<MyClassA>();` If you want to make writing a bit easier..

Comment: What is the exact error message you are getting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The signature is:

```
IRestResponse<T> Execute<T>(IRestRequest request) where T : new();
```

The [generic constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx) of [`new`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx) does not allow abstract classes. 
Instead you can:

1. Have an interface for your classes and have a generic constraint on that.
2. Change your `MyClassA` to not being abstract
3. Remove the constraint

*Me personally - I'd say the interface option - but this is opinion based :)*

In any case for the `PerformExecuteClient<T>` it must follow at least the generic constraints of the `Execute<T>` which it executes.

Comment: Since the restclient comes from an external library, I can't remove the constraint. Using an interface for my classes does solve the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Happy it gave you a solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Did you try this:

```
private RestResponse<T> PerformExecuteClient<T>() where T : new()
{
    return client.Execute<T>();
}
```

As everyone pointed out here, you have to follow the interface's generic constraint to make this work. If you don't, you do not respect the interface contract by passing an unexpected type.

Also `where T : new()` means that you can instantiate `T` like this `new T()`. But by definition, an abstract class can't be instantiate, that is why you get this error.

Answer (score 1):

This :

```
where T : new();
```

Means that `T` will be created inside of method. But how can you create instance of abstract class ? Hence an error.

Answer (score 0):

The Execute method on the client object could have a where `T: [Something]` constraint, which your generic method would also need to apply.  Look at the source code (if possible) or documentation to see if a where constraint is applied to the generic.